# How can I succinctly but correctly say that a set is finite?

Tags: terminology

If I want to say that a set $A$ is numerable but infinite, I can do so like this: $$|A| = \aleph_0$$

What *should* I use instead to say that a set is finite? $|A|\in\mathbb{N}$? $|A|< \infty$? $|A|< \aleph_0$? Something else entirely?

Comment: I'm hacking together a reference sheet so space is at a premium. :)

Comment: "The set A is not infinite".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In light of your comment below the question (in addition to "What should I use instead to say that a set is finite?"), I suggest using $|A| < |\mathbb{N}|$ (or $|A| < \aleph _0$); see Wikipedia's definition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality#Finite.2C_countable_and_uncountable_sets) and Theorem (5.4) [here](http://bolyai.cs.elte.hu/~karolyik/INTRO.pdf). Note that this allows $A$ to be empty (the empty set is finite, and has a cardinality of zero).

EDIT: Exact quotations from the above links: 1) "Any set $X$ with cardinality less than that of the natural numbers, or $|X| < |\mathbf{N}|$, is said to be a finite set" (where $\mathbf{N}=\lbrace 0,1,2,3,\ldots\rbrace $); 2) "A set $X$ is finite if and only if $|X| < |\mathbb{N}^+|$" (where $\mathbb{N}^+ = \lbrace 1,2,3, \ldots \rbrace$).

Comment: The empty set is finite, I believe. What does that mean $|X|<\mathbb N^+$ anyway? Do you mean $\in$?

Comment: @Asaf: I meant to write $|X| < |\mathbb{N}^+|$ (as in that link); I'll fix this. Concerning the comment about the empty set, I see no problem with what I wrote.

Comment: Very well. If $|X|<|\mathbb N^+|$ then it holds for the empty set, I was thinking it was meant to be $\in$ which would then imply the empty set is not finite :-)

Comment: @Asaf: Thanks for this reply.

Answer (score 27):

You should say "The set $A$ is finite." There is nothing wrong with using sentences in mathematics; they often are easier for the reader to understand than a sequence of symbols.

Comment: Unless the "reader" is a computer, in which case a symbolic language is far more precise.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply, "$A$ is finite" or $|A| = n$.

Comment: While "A is finite" is fine, "$|A|=n$" makes me ask _What is $n$??_ ($n=\aleph_0$?) You'll have to write "$|A|\in\mathbb N$" as in Swlabr's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* say,

"There does not exist an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$."

Personally, however, I would just go with either "$A$ is finite" or "$|A| <\infty$". It does depend on the context though.

Comment: If $A$ is amorphous then there is no injection from $\mathbb N$ into $A$, but $A$ is most certainly not finite.

Comment: I have never come across amorphous sets, but they seem to assume $\lnot AC$ in their definition. Which is silly.

Comment: What you <i>can</i> do is not always such a good idea.

Comment: Why is it silly not to assume $AC$?

Comment: ...you mean you are happy with only the one orange?...

Comment: (The `it is silly' was just my initial bias, but the more I think about it the more odd I believe it *is* silly. I mean, AOC is independent of ZF, so one can prove stuff in ZF and then it should holds in ZFC...but amorphous sets seem to go against this. There exist things in ZF which do not exist in ZFC. This is, I believe, silly...unless I am missing something?)

Comment: Yes, you are missing the point that there are many things which are very interesting and only happen without the axiom of choice. In particular amorphous sets. I do not see why giving a definition which does not hold *without* the axiom of choice is a good idea when there are *cleaner* definitions which hold just fine in $ZF$.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, I just don't understand how it can be true if AC is independent of ZF. I was meaning, unless I am missing something from this independence...

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of style I would say, "$A$ is finite."  It is best to avoid having a bristling obstacle course of symbols for your reader to penetrate.  Which is easier to read here?

Every nonvoid subset of the positive integers has a least element.

$\forall \emptyset \subset S\subseteq {\Bbb N}$, $ \exists m\in S$ such that $m\le s$ $\forall s\in S.$

The choice is clear to me.  Use notation and symbols to simplify and clarify.

Comment: I'm not clear about your use of $\emptyset$ in that formula. Did you mean $\emptyset\subsetneq S$?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: To me $\subset$ is a strict, $\subseteq$ is nonstrict.

Comment: I think I got it three years ago. :-P