# Symbol for finite

Tags: notation

I understand there is a symbol for infinite. Is there one for finite?

I searched and found there is none. How is finite represented symbolically?

Comment: In writing, you'll probably be better off being clear and using words, not symbols.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49782/how-can-i-succinctly-but-correctly-say-that-a-set-is-finite)?

Comment: @lhf: do you mean to say that symbols will be more handy than words when *talking*?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have never seen a notation for 'finite,' but what I do very often see is denoting something finite as simply being less than infinity.  For example, $|A| < \infty$, or $[G:H] < \infty$.

Small thing  I'd like to add: Of course something like $[G:H] < \infty$ isn't technically meaningful, but it certainly gets the point across and in my experience at least seems to be pretty standard.

Comment: What's not technically meaningful about it? It's a comparison between two cardinalities.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: True, it does work in that case if we let $\infty$ represent some transfinite cardinal number.  I should have used the second example there, and in fact I will edit it.  (and sorry for the late reply)

Comment: I don't see what's not technically meaningful about $[G : H] < \infty$ either. You are committing a fairly small abuse of notation in identifying a finite cardinal with a natural number. One can make perfect sense of the poset $\{ 1, 2, ... \infty \}$.

Comment: One can write $|[G:H]|<\infty$.  The notation $|[G:H]|$ means the number of members of $[G:H]$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you mean the symbol $\infty$, for a non-specific non-finite cardinality. In this case, in the same way you would say $|X|=\infty$ to mean "the set $X$ has infinitely many elements", I would write $|X|<\infty$ to mean "the set $X$ has finitely many elements".

Comment: He doesn't say he is working with cardinals.  When we have a function $f$ with (according to its definition) values in the extended real numbers $[-\infty,+\infty]$, and we want to emphasize that a certain value $f(x)$ is finite, we may write $|f(x)| < \infty$.  When we have a series $\sum a_n$ and we want to say it converges absolutely, we may write $\sum |a_n|<\infty$.

Comment: Sure, I used cardinals as an example. (This is why I like Alex's answer better, because he gives two examples).

Answer (score 4):

How about using $$\not\infty$$

Comment: I had the same idea, but didn't know \not.

Comment: You might want to consider using "\!" a few times to write $\not\!\!\infty$. Just typographical concerns ;)

Comment: It just doesn't look any good ):

Comment: Does anyone know if the unicode symbol ⧞ = 29DE (infinity negated with vertical bar) was meant to be used in situations like this?

Comment: Wow, this is almost perfect if it is centered!